# pywinauto: MenuSelect() Cannot be used to select "MenuBar" in some applications. What is a suitable function from this library to use?

Tags: python, windows, menubar, pywinauto

I automate tests for an application called "Team Developer" belongs to Gupta Technology. It has a Menu bar not a menu. I'm not able to select the menu by MenuSelect(), and it shows "raise RuntimeError("There is no menu.")" error.

```
import pywinauto
import time

from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application.start('C:\Program Files (x86)\Gupta\Team Developer.exe')
pywinauto.application.Application()
time.sleep(2)
MenuItms = app.window_(title_re = "Gupta*").MenuSelect("File->Exit")
```

How can I select an Item from menu bar?
I also have used "Swapy" to get the correct python code for pywinauto, but no useful results.

Comment: MenuBar is currently not supported by pywinauto. Probably future UIA extensions will support it. Though a MenuBar support looks possible to implement in the native back-end as well. But it's not a highest priority now. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, Thank you. Hope to have it soon. :)

Comment: Feature request in the bug tracker: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/104

Comment: Inspect.exe doesn't see menu bar items (so UIA is not a silver bullet for that). But I could interpret menu bar as a toolbar and it partially works! There is another problem: button rectangles and texts are not available.

Comment: Rectangles problem is solved now (in <master> branch). But texts can be available using mixed native/UIA approach as far as I know. Drop-down sub-menus are also toolbars inside new top-level windows. So now it's simple to click first level menu item by `app.Dialog.MenuBar.Button(0).ClickInput()` but it's hard to workaround  clicking second and other levels of the menu. I'm working on simpler shortcut for that.

Comment: The shortcut method is working for `RebarTest.exe` from here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/master/apps/MFC_samples Will test it better and commit then. It should look like `app.RebarTest.MenuBar.MenuClickInput('#1->#0->#0', app) # View->Toolbars->Customize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu bar can be re-interpreted as a toolbar now. Button texts are not available though (it can be done using mixed native/UIA approach much later). You can try [latest  branch of pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/master.zip) (run `python setup.py install`).

This is an example with `RebarTest.exe` sample app (running from the repo root folder):

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.Application().start_(r'.\apps\MFC_samples\x64\RebarTest.exe')
app.RebarTest.MenuBar.MenuBarClickInput('#1->#0->#0', app) # View->Toolbars->Customize
app.Customize.CloseButton.Click()
app.Customize.WaitNot('visible')

app.RebarTest.MenuBar.MenuBarClickInput([2, 0], app)
app.Window_(title='About RebarTest').OK.Click()
app.Window_(title='About RebarTest').WaitNot('visible')
```

Please try this workaround for your app and let us know if it works.

Comment: The example works perfectly for the sample "RebarTest.exe", but it shows following error when I try it on my app.    "AttributeError: 'HwndWrapper' object has no attribute 'MenuBarClick'"

Comment: Could you please provide the output of your `HwndWrapper` object method `Class()`?

Comment: >'['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', >'__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', >'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']'    I hope this is what you mean. Please let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: No, I mean window class name like what `app.RebarTest.MenuBar.Class()` returns. :)

Comment: I got it! Probably you mean :  'app.window_(title_re="Gupta*").MenuBar.MenuBarClick('#1->#1', app)'  Returns 'File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.3-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 245, in __getattr__
    return getattr(ctrls[-1], attr)'

Comment: Please provide return value of `app.window_(title_re="Gupta*").MenuBar.Class()` or `app.window_(title_re="Gupta*").MenuBar.WrapperObject().Class()`. It should be one Python string like `"Afx:Toolbar:<many digits>"`.

Comment: I mean exactly return value, not a crash traceback. `Class()` is a different method than `MenuBarClickInput()`. I wanna `Class()` return value. `Class()` should not crash.

Comment: u'ProfUIS-DockBar'  This is the output. I hope finally I'm right. Sorry, I sometimes behave dumb :) So, does it mean it is not an actual MenuBar?

Comment: OK, that's what I requested. It might be a menu bar, but not necessarily.

Comment: This is the new error, after trying with the latest update.

Comment: OK, now I can say pywinauto 0.5.x is not able to automate this control gracefully. Let's wait for 0.6.x this winter or try another solutions.

Comment: Or try to examine the controls hierarchy with SWAPY. Maybe the dock bar has some child control with toolbar-like behavior.