# Trying with python script to do GUI automation but stuck with menu select operation

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to GUI automation of ADS software and for that I am using Python scripting. But I am getting error while working on menu select.

I have tried with SWAPY automation tool to get syntax but no major help from that and then I have tried with below link but still no success. [pywinauto: MenuSelect() Cannot be used to select "MenuBar" in some applications. What is a suitable function from this library to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113913/pywinauto-menuselect-cannot-be-used-to-select-menubar-in-some-applications)

```
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> import pywinauto
>>> from pywinauto import findwindows
>>> app = pywinauto.Application().start(r"C:\Program Files\Keysight\ADS2020\bin\ads.exe")
>>> app = Application().connect(title=u'Advanced Design System 2020 (Main)', class_name='Qt5QWindowIcon')
>>> MenuItms = app.window_(title=u'Advanced Design System 2020 (Main)').MenuSelect("File->Exit")

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
DeprecationWarning: Method .window_() is deprecated, use .window() instead.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
DeprecationWarning: Method .MenuSelect() is deprecated, use .menu_select() instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    MenuItms = app.window_(title=u'Advanced Design System 2020 (Main)').MenuSelect("File->Exit")
  File "C:\Users\aakotkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 50, in wrap
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aakotkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\hwndwrapper.py", line 1083, in menu_select
    self.menu_item(path, exact=exact).select()
  File "C:\Users\aakotkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\hwndwrapper.py", line 1028, in menu_item
    raise RuntimeError("There is no menu.")
RuntimeError: There is no menu.
```

It should click on File and then select Exit

Comment: done more on this and now getting below error.             
 app.connect(title=u'Advanced Design System 2020 (Main)', class_name='Qt5QWindowIcon')
<pywinauto.application.Application object at 0x000002B745847208>
>>> m = app.top_window().Menu()

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
DeprecationWarning: Method .Menu() is deprecated, use .menu() instead.
>>> m = app.top_window().menu()
>>> m.Items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    m.Items()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Items'
>>>