# pywinauto access a nested submenue

Tags: python, pywinauto

In pywinauto I am trying to access a nested submenue item that contains.
The Path is Datei->Importieren->Vorlagen->comdirect Musterdepot (attached screenshot)

Any idea how I can get this running?

The code I use:

```
app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(path = "PortfolioPerformance.exe")
app.Dialog.Anwendungsmenü.item_by_path('Datei->Importieren->Vorlagen->comdirect Musterdepot').click_input()
```

The error I receive:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Screenshot of Menu:
[image: Path of the Submenu]

Comment: Please check if the double arrow (`->->` ) in `'Vorlagen->->comdirect Musterdepot'` might be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, the double arrow happened accidently when copying the code. It does not cause the issue.

Comment: Reading from previous answers on similar issues, please try and see if changing to menu numbers help. i.e, instead of `Datei->Importieren->Vorlagen->comdirect Musterdepot'` use `#0->#8->#2->#0`. See this answer for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33301892/12950723

Comment: I also tried it with the hash variables , i.e. #0->#8->#2->#0 which does have the same outcome. The Problem is that the script always raises the AttributeError on the third level of the Menue.

i.e. Datei->Speichern is working, Datei->Importieren is working, Datei->Importieren->comdirect Musterdepot is failing, Datei->Speichern unter->XML is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time I figured out the following behaviour:
Once I expanded the Datei Menu, the print_control_identifiers updated to include the submenues.
The following code will click the correct, but maybe there are nicer solutions out there:

```
app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(path = PROCNAME)
dialog = app.dialog
#first open the Importieren submenu:
dialog.Anwendungsmenü.item_by_path('Datei->Importieren') 
# then the submenue appears on top level menues, open the importieren menu:
dialog["Importieren"].item_by_path('Vorlagen->comdirect Musterdepot').select()
```